# PostgreSQL -- JOIN UNNEST output with CTE INSERT ID -- INSERT many to many

Tags: postgresql, postgraphile

In a PostgreSQL function, is it possible to join the result of UNNEST, which is an integer array from function input, with an ID returned from a CTE INSERT?

I have PostgreSQL tables like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.message (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    content TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE public.message_tag (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    message_id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT message_tag_message_id_fkey REFERENCES public.message(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT message_tag_tag_id_fkey REFERENCES public.tag(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I want to create a PostgreSQL function which takes input of `content` and an array of `tag_id`. This is for graphile. I want to do it all in one function, so I get a mutation.

Here's what I got so far. I don't know how to join an `UNNEST` across an id returned from a CTE.

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.create_message(content text, tags Int[])
RETURNS public.message
AS $$

-- insert to get primary key of message, for many to many message_id
WITH moved_rows AS (
  INSERT INTO public.message (content)
  RETURNING *;
)

-- many to many relation
INSERT INTO public.message_tag
SELECT moved_rows.id as message_id, tagInput.tag_id  FROM moved_rows, UNNEST(tags) as tagInput;
RETURNING *

$$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not that far from your goal:

- the semicolon placement in the CTE is wrong
- the first `INSERT` statement lacks a `SELECT` or `VALUES` clause to specify *what* should be inserted
- the `INSERT` into `tag_message` should specify the columns in which to insert (especially if you have that unnecessary serial `id`)
- you specified a relation alias for the `UNNEST` call already, but none for the column `tag_id`
- your function was `RETURNING` a set of `message_tag` rows but was specified to return a single `message` row

To fix these:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.create_message(content text, tags Int[])
RETURNS public.message
AS $$

-- insert to get primary key of message, for many to many message_id
WITH moved_rows AS (
  INSERT INTO public.message (content)
  VALUES ($1)
  RETURNING *
),
-- many to many relation
_ AS (
INSERT INTO public.message_tag (message_id, tag_id)
SELECT moved_rows.id, tagInput.tag_id
FROM moved_rows, UNNEST($2) as tagInput(tag_id)
)
TABLE moved_rows;

$$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

<sub>([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ed7cd379cfae788a23bfad31fa32b494))</sub>

Comment: Is it possible to return the message_tags too? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=24875171bd392cecf2acf39c2bfdb981 I added RETURNS setof per graphile docs https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/relations/#many-to-many-relations Thank you so much.

Comment: got it! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8976eaef04d615994b7b9d14b1fa3607

Comment: I thought you were going to do `mutation { createMessage(…) { id text tags { name } } }` anyway, so returning the created message is more important